# RF signal Wi-Fi leak

Tags: wifi, wireless

How can one steal files off a laptop hard drive using RF / Wi-Fi signals? Can it be done with the laptop powered off if there is a battery?

Comment: Theoretically, WakeOnWLAN is possible, but unless you have a hardware that supports that feature and you've enabled it, a device that's powered down aren't going to be infected just by wifi signals. Even with WOWLAN, it's going to take multiple vulnerabilities to infect a machine woken up in a such a way

Comment: If you are close enough to be on the same wifi, why not steal the laptop? So make sure it has an encrypted hard drive. This is all hypothetical of course.

Comment: This is really, really broad unless you meant to include some other details. Using WiFi, I could connect to the laptop's RDP port, brute force the login, then simply browse and transfer any file I want. Were there more details you meant to include?

Comment: That's what I'm asking @schroeder could you please explain in an answer how you would do that, step by step, and if and how you would be able to do that with the laptop powered off if there is a battery?

Comment: No. I just gave one example. There are numerous other options. A device that is off  is off. Can I make a guess that you think you've had files stolen and you are wondering how it happened?

Comment: It's theoretical, not to do with my files.  there is no existing step by step explanation of how to steal files using RF / WIFI signals online or how to connect to the laptop's RDF port, brute force the login and transfer the files. I'm asking for a step by step explanation of that

Comment: We are not a hacking tutorial site.