# How does one steal files by connecting to a laptop's WIFI / Bluetooth?

Tags: wireless

I'm asking how does one steal files by connecting to a laptop's WIFI / Bluetooth and can it be done with the laptop powered off if there is a battery?

Could you please explain how you would connect to a laptop's WIFI / Bluetooth and brute force the login, step by step?

I'm not asking for a hacking tutorial as misunderstood by someone, this is for educational purposes so I can understand it better. There is no existing explanation of that online.

Comment: What is an RDF port?

Comment: Radio frequency. WIFI and Bluetooth on a laptop

Comment: [Based on your previous question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/220178/rf-signal-wi-fi-leak#comment447430_220178), are you asking about the RDP Port as mentioned by [schroeder](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/6253/schroeder)? RDP is "Remote Desktop Protocol" and is a way to remotely connect to a computer over a network (WiFi or otherwise). https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028379/windows-10-how-to-use-remote-desktop

Comment: @user220481: what has the "port" to do with WiFi and Bluetooth? Since I cannot find anything like an "RDF port" with your description would you please provide some reference (wikipedia, vendor manual...) to what you mean?

Comment: The RDF was mentioned in my earlier post by schroeder about stealing files by brute forcing the RDP Port. Please see my edit, I'm asking for an explanation of how one steals files by connecting to a laptop's WIFI or Bluetooth with physical proximity but no internet

Comment: *"There is no existing explanation of that online."* - this is because there is no such thing. There might be a chain of attacks though which can lead to data exfiltration and start with exploiting a [bug in the drivers for WiFi or Bluetooth](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/broadcom-wifi-driver-flaws-expose-computers-phones-iot-to-rce-attacks/) or by [cracking WPA](https://hakin9.org/crack-wpa-wpa2-wi-fi-routers-with-aircrack-ng-and-hashcat/) in order to enter the network of the user.

Comment: Step by step explanations for such hacking  would be both too broad but also off-topic here though, no matter if you want to use it for educational purpose or not.

Comment: Also note that some laptops support WoWLAN (wake-on-wireless LAN), so even if a laptop is "off" it may be possible to make it boot up and attack it when it's running. Most implementations of this that I've seen require the laptop to be in a suspended state instead of off though.

Comment: I understand nothing of your question. If you're asking if it's possible to leak data from a powered off device. No, it's impossible. 

Someone COULD fake a "powered off", provided the machine has previously been hacked and/or tempered with.

Comment: Do not re-post closed questions

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a repost of a closed question

Comment: I already walked you through the "steps" in your previous question. To ask for the detailed explanation *is* asking for a tutorial. And, I said **RDP** not **RDF**

Answer (score 0):

1. If they have physical access the laptop's wireless devices can be hacked, while it does not display as connected, it is connecting to a Wifi hotspot of theirs to send your files.
2. the laptop is on or in a suspended state and they are within Wifi range they can exploit vulnerabilities in the laptop's drivers and hardware and send the files.
3. WakeonWLAN could be exploited and the files sent when the laptop is running again.